# .htaccess rewrite subdirectory to parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a page template that exists at a directory:

```
/users/
```

I would like to use the page template at this level, call it index.php for any other sub directories within this directory

```
/users/firstname-lastname/
```

Essentially using the next directory as a clean query string to dictate what is on the index.php page.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I have /users/index.php and I would like /users/firstname-lastname/ to use that index.php file instead of thinking I am requesting a directory further down. It seems so simple but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2 -d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(users)/(.+)$ /$1/index.php [NC,L]
```